# How apps are getting locations when Background Restrictions are turned on?

Tags: android, location, background-service, google-geolocation, google-location-services

Some android devices have options to restrict apps in the background to save battery consumption. If I will turn on this option, my app and its background service will be killed. Some apps like Uber, Careem etc are using google services to get location of driver, to track driver.
I tested Uber Driver app, I turned on this option, and then killed the Uber Driver app. Location of driver was not updating, from pickup to drop off, location of driver was not updated. When I opened the driver's app to end the ride, location of driver updated, and whole distance was calculated accurately.
My question is this, if app is restricted to be used and killed, then on opening app, from where it gets all the locations, how Uber app knows the travelled distance?

Please have a look on attached images, devices have options like these[image]:
[image]

Comment: I'm assuming they are using Google's service. Even if you tell Android to not allow Uber get locations, Uber is asking Google's services what was the "path" you've been through. How they are asking, I don't know I have not used such APIs but I wouldn't be surprised if it's simply there

Comment: Yes, probably they are using Google services, but I am unable to know that which service?

Comment: @DanBaruch No, Google doesn't have a location history API.  But they could get the same data from the rider's phone.  Or they could be assuming you followed the suggested route and calculating based on that, since they knew where you were when the ride started.

Comment: The API Google Play Service API does have for location is just a drop in replacement for GPS that makes different accuracy/battery tradeoffs.